# callback after react setState functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two actions in react. To add a second field and scroll to it. If I use setTimeout on ref.scrollIntoView this will work but I don't need this ugly workaround. I also heard that I can use useEffect to subscribe on state and then move scroll. But I have five functions that also uses this state and I don't need to subscribe in those different functions (for example when I change name) I don't need a scroll. I simulate adding new items and if there is no space for last item (under the screen) scroll to the last item.

```
function addItem() {
 const data = [{name: 'lex'}];
 const newData = data.push({name: 'Ted'})
  setState(newData);
  ref.scrollIntoView({behavior: auto, block: end});//can't scroll becase state is setting right now
//setTimeout(()=> {ref.scroll...}, 0) works
}

return <div ref={ref}>{state.map((item) => <p>item.name</p>}</div>
```

Comment: The only appropriate solution to this need is usage of `useEffect` hook. But I couldn't understand when you need to call the scrollIntoView method. When state has 2 elements  `[{ name: 'lex' }, { name: 'Ted' }]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wait for state to update:

```
useEffect(() => {
  ref.scrollIntoView({behavior: auto, block: end});
}, [state.length])
```

Comment: what if I have setState when I rename function. So it also will be triggered. The only thing is came to me is adding a new state and twitching it.

ref.scroll(...) setScroll(!scroll)


useEffect(()=.{}, [scroll])

but it seems to much or I am wrong

Comment: @Lex you can use `state.length`

Comment: wow, never thougt about that. If I want to add /remove I can keep tracking previus lenght and actual lenght and make stuff